# Can I use one data entry page to enter data into multiple tables in the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm a beginner when it comes to the MVC framework, and I'm trying to figure out how to use the framework to insert data from 1 data entry page into 2 database tables.

From what I know, you use a Model to describe the type of data you'd like to input. Now, if I have a model with 5 columns in it (table_shape, table_height, table_material, quantity, table_manufacturer), how would I go about inserting the first 4 items (and a reference to the unique id in the second table) into one database table, and the table_manufacturer  (with a unique id) into a second table?

Or is this something that needs to be done within the stored procedures of the database itself?  And if so, how would one go about that?

Thanks for your help and let me know if something is unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is not a Data access technology. Just get the values from the form in your action method and then save it using your favorite data access technology (perhaps separated abstracted by another data access layer in your solution).

Are you using Entity Framework? Validate the model, then create a new TableInformation entity, and another Manufacturer entity. Connect both entities and then save them. This will have them connected with a foreign key in your database.

You need to read about Entity Framework and ASP .NET MVC. Remember ASP .NET MVC is not a data access technology. Your question is more about how to use Entity Framework or other ORM. But then, you can still use ADO .NET.